# does current subscription version of Acrobat offer better javascript support than one time purchase Acrobat Pro 2020?

Tags: javascript, acrobat

I'm not a certified programmer, but have experience working with VBA for Excel and Word at work and I'm familiar with programming in General and would like to think a quick learner! I have coded several practical VBA applications over the years and I keep researching and building up on VBA coding skills. I need to expand my experience to javascript to include PDF forms projects at work. I'm trying to figure out if I need to bite the bullet and get a subscription to the latest Acrobat Pro version or if I can buy a discounted Acrobat Pro 2020 version which is more affordable. Adobe's website is not that clear if the support of javascript is the same; I found conflicting information. I would appreciate any input from experienced real programmers out there.
thanks.

I tried online research and documentation, got a copy of John Deubert "Extending Acrobat Forms with JavaScript". But that book was written before mentioned versions of Acrobat

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I could see, there are no (or only minimal) differences.

In any case, I suggest to go to the developer section of the Adobe website, and download the Acrobat SDK (documentation), where you have the necessary documents for your work.

Comment: Thanks . for the suggestion, I'll do that